# Integration Question $\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^4 + 3x^2 + 1}$

Tags: integration

Is anyone able to check the answer to my integration question.

$$
\int \frac{x^2-1}{x^4 + 3 x^2 + 1} dx.
$$
 EDIT: by using $$u = 1 + \frac{1}{x^2}$$ as a substitution
Is the answer to the question $\tan^{-1}(x + 1/x)$.

I'll provide working out as soon as I finish my dinner. Cheers for editing my Q.

I divided both the numerator and denominator by $x^2$, the factor in the numerator was cancelled.

$$
\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2 + 3 + \frac{1}{x^2}}dx.$$

Comment: writing out in the question how you arrived at this answer would be helpful.

Comment: You could try to differentiate $\arctan (x + 1/x)$, and check if it is equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $x\ne0,$

$$\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+3x^2+1}=\frac{1-\dfrac1{x^2}}{\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)^2+1}$$

$$\frac{d\left(x+\dfrac1x\right)}{dx}=?$$